# Relative layout isn't working on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

Basically, I'm learning Android development and am having trouble with adding a relative layout to my code. Inside the main linear layout, it simply won't work and I don't know how to add another outside (is that possible?). I don't know how to fix this and I would just like to know what I need to write in order to get a relative layout with some text in the top right corner, as I can't do this efficiently with a linear layout. Please help. The text I want in the top right corner is "Open from 8 AM to 6 PM on Mondays to Fridays \n \n Open from 9 PM to 5 PM on Saturdays and Sundays".

Here is my code:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.janis.justjava.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    
    <TextView
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Quantity"
        android:textAllCaps="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="38dp"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            android:text="-"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:onClick="decrement"/>

        <TextView
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/quantity_text_view"
            android:text="0"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="38dp"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            android:text="+"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:onClick="increment"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Price"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:textAllCaps="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/price_text_view"
        android:text="Total: £0"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

I can send my Java code too if that is helpful.

Here is how the code looks on android studio:

[Pic of the android studio with phone preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLwLp.png)

Comment: Add the expected result layout in question .

Comment: where you want to add relative layout ?

Comment: I dont get it... You want `RelativeLayout` but use `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure of what your requirement is but I think it should be something like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Quantity"
        android:textAllCaps="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="38dp"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            android:text="-"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:onClick="decrement"/>

        <TextView
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/quantity_text_view"
            android:text="0"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="38dp"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            android:text="+"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:onClick="increment"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Price"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:textAllCaps="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/price_text_view"
        android:text="Total: £0"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/container"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Open from 8AM to 6PM on Mondays to Fridays \n \n Open from 9PM to 5PM on Saturdays and Sundays"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Copy this and have a try at it.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't understand why you need `RelativeLayout`. If you want to align the text to the top-right corner, you can do in your existing layout. Just add `TextView` with `width=match_parent` and `gravity=end`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              tools:context="com.example.janis.justjava.MainActivity"
              android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:text="Open from 8 AM to 6 PM on Mondays to Fridays \n \n Open from 9 PM to 5 PM on Saturdays and Sundays"/>
    <TextView
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Quantity"
        android:textAllCaps="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="38dp"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            android:text="-"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:onClick="decrement"/>

        <TextView
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/quantity_text_view"
            android:text="0"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="38dp"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            android:text="+"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:onClick="increment"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Price"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:textAllCaps="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/price_text_view"
        android:text="Total: £0"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Here is the expected output]

I hope this solves your problem.